# Is == a special method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, equality

I understand that `x == y` in Ruby interpreted as `a.==(y)`. I tried to check if I can achieve the same with custom method, `foo`, like this:

```
class Object
  def foo(n)
    self == n
  end
end

class A
  attr_accessor :x
end

a = A.new
a.x = 4

puts a.x.==(4)   # => true
puts a.x.foo(4)  # => true

puts a.x == 4    # => true
puts a.x foo 4   # => in `x': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. What am I missing ? Is `==` a special method in Ruby ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, `==` is not a special method in Ruby. It's a method like any other. What you are seeing is simply a parsing issue:

```
a.x foo 4
```

is the same as

```
a.x(foo(4))
```

IOW, you are passing `foo(4)` as an argument to `x`, but `x` doesn't take any arguments.

There *is*, however, special operator *syntax*, which allows you to write

```
a == b
```

instead of

```
a.== b
```

for a limited list of operators:

```
==
!=
<
>
<=
>=
<=>
===
&
|
*
/
+
-
%
**
>>
<<
!==
=~
!~
```

Also, there is special syntax that allows you to write

```
!a
```

and

```
~a
```

instead of

```
a.!
```

and

```
a.~
```

As well as

```
+a
```

and

```
-a
```

instead of

```
a.+@
```

and

```
a.-@
```

Then, there is

```
a[b]
```

and

```
a[b] = c
```

instead of

```
a.[] b
```

and

```
a.[]= b, c
```

and last but not least

```
a.(b)
```

instead of

```
a.call b
```

Answer (score 2):

Methods that are operators are treated specially in Ruby, at least syntax-wise. The language is not as flexible as, say, in Haskell where you can turn any function into an infix operator by enclosing its name in backticks: the list on infix operators are pre-determined.

One of the problems that would arise from custom infixes is the handling of operator precedence and associativity: for eaxmple, how would the parser handle a statement like:

```
a foo b == c # should this be (a foo b) == c or a foo (b == c)
```